# snake does not catch the fruit when i increase the snake_block to 20. I don’t understand what code should I change

Tags: python, object, pygame, pycharm

I’m new in python and have used pygame to make this snake game. But it lacks when i increase the snake_block and keep it as 20. The snake does not eat the fruit. It works well when the snake_block is 10. I tried to find the solution but didn’t find any... Also want know how can i add highscore and levels to this game.
Here is source code:

```
#importing libraries
import pygame
import time
import random

#initialising pygame 
pygame.init()

#defining colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)

#size of game window
dis_width = 1200
dis_height = 700

#initialising game window 
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game by Sakshi')

#track time
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 10

direction = "right"
snake_List = []
Length_of_snake = 1

#creating font object for score
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
font_width = 0
font_height = 0

#sound effects
game_over_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("./sounds/game_over1.wav")
food_ate_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("./sounds/food_eaten.wav")

#defining score
def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score * 5), True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])

#defining snake 
def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])
 
#defining message to be printed on screen
def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])

#defining pause function    
def pause():
    paused = True
    message("Game is Paused. Press 'C' to continue or 'Q' to quit",white)

    # updates the screen
    pygame.display.update()
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("here")
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    paused = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        #gameDisplay.fill(white)
        clock.tick(5) 

#defining gameloop
def gameLoop():

    game_over = False
    game_close = False
    game_start = False

    #snake dimensions
    x1 = dis_width / 2
    y1 = dis_height / 2
 
    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    # direction
    direction = 'RIGHT'
    change_to = direction

    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1


    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

    while not game_over:
        change_direction = False

        while game_close == True:
            dis.fill(blue)
            #message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", red)
            value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str((Length_of_snake - 1) * 5), True, yellow)
            dis.blit(value, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])
            value = score_font.render("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", True, yellow)
            dis.blit(value, [(dis_width / 6), (dis_height / 3)+30])
            pygame.display.update()
            
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()
 
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            #handling key events
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    change_to = 'UP'
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    change_to = 'DOWN'
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    change_to = 'LEFT'
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    change_to = 'RIGHT'
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    paused = True
                    pause()
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    sound_effect = pygame.mixer.Sound(game_over_sound)
                    sound_effect.play()
                    pygame.time.delay(1000)
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True

        #Don't want snake to move in same direction simultaneously
        if change_to == 'UP' and direction != 'DOWN':
            direction = 'UP'
        if change_to == 'DOWN' and direction != 'UP':
            direction = 'DOWN'
        if change_to == 'LEFT' and direction != 'RIGHT':
            direction = 'LEFT'
        if change_to == 'RIGHT' and direction != 'LEFT':
            direction = 'RIGHT'

        #moving the snake
        if direction == 'UP':
            y1_change = -snake_block
            x1_change = 0
        if direction == 'DOWN':
            y1_change = snake_block
            x1_change = 0
        if direction == 'LEFT':
            x1_change = -snake_block
            y1_change = 0
        if direction == 'RIGHT':
            x1_change = snake_block
            y1_change = 0


        if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
            sound_effect = pygame.mixer.Sound(game_over_sound)
            sound_effect.play()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            game_close = True
            
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        dis.fill(blue)
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, green, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        #dis.blit((foodx, foody))
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]
 
        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True
        
        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        #when snake eats the food
        #print(foodx, foody,snake_block,x1, y1 )
        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
            sound_effect = food_ate_sound.play()
            pygame.time.delay(100)
 
        clock.tick(snake_speed)
 
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
    
def start_game():
    while True:
        dis.fill(red)
        value = score_font.render("Welcome to the Snake Game", True, yellow)
        dis.blit(value, [dis_width / 10, dis_height / 3])
        value = score_font.render("Game Rules are:", True, yellow)
        dis.blit(value, [dis_width / 10, (dis_height / 3)+30])
        value = score_font.render("Press 'S' to Start, 'C' to continue and 'P' to Pause", True, yellow)
        dis.blit(value, [dis_width / 10, (dis_height / 3)+60])
        value = score_font.render("Press left, right, up and down arrow keys to move left, right, up and down respectively", True, yellow)
        dis.blit(value, [dis_width / 10, (dis_height / 3)+90])
        value = score_font.render("Press 'Q' to quit", True, yellow)
        dis.blit(value, [dis_width / 10, (dis_height / 3)+120])
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    gameLoop()
                '''elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    paused = True
                    pause()'''

        pygame.display.update()

start_game()
#for event in pygame.event.get():
    #if event.key == 'S' or event.key == 's':
#gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of the foods position is wrong. You need to consider the size of a block:

<s>`foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0`

`foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0`</s>

```py
foodx = random.randrange(dis_width // snake_block) * snake_block
foody = random.randrange(dis_height // snake_block) * snake_block
```